# How to find one collection item by an arbitrary property, but not _id, in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, minimongo

I have an application that uses Flow Router and its pub/sub mechanics. I also have a collection and template helpers. The code is, on client

```
Template.theCase.helpers({
    theCase: function () {
        var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        var theCase = Cases.findOne({
            id: id
        });

        return theCase;
    }
});
```

and

```
{{#with theCase}}
  {{ id }}
{{/with}}
```

then, on server

```
Meteor.publish('theCase', function (id) {
    return Cases.findOne({
        id: id
    });
});
```

and finally, on both (`lib`)

```
FlowRouter.route('/case/:id', {
    subscriptions: function (params) {
        this.register('theCase', Meteor.subscribe('theCase', params.id));
    },
    action: function (params, queryParams) {
        return BlazeLayout.render('container');
    }
});
```

The problem, as I see it, is that helper returns `undefined`, since it's not allowed to find items in a collection by any other property than `_id`. How can I overcome it? I've read truckload of the official docs on pub/sub, helpers and routing, and I just can't find the solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can query by any field. The helper returns undefined because it didn't find anything that matched.

This code is problematic:

```
Meteor.publish('theCase', function (id) {
    return Cases.findOne({
        id: id
    });
});
```

It should be: `return Cases.find({id: id});`

Publications must return a cursor or call `this.ready()`

Comment: The problem I'm having is precisely because I want to use custom identity instead of mongo-generated `_id`. I have a property that is essentially a number and it increments. I know it may be the anti-pattern, but it's exactly the problem I'm attacking.

Comment: There could be reasons to use id. That's not a problem. I just edited my answer. I'd recommend printing logs to see that what you're actually expecting to find exists.

Comment: I found a problem with your publication and edited my answer

Comment: You were right, `Cases.find({...})` didn't return any value because `id` is String. Simply converting it to Number solved the issue. I'm dumb.